# Dynamically naming Arrays/Hashes in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, variables, dynamic, naming

So I have a for loop thats creating a hash or array depending on whats being passed in.

I need to create these arrays and Hashes with names based on whats being passed in.

Its much the same as

```
window['MyNewArray-' + i] = [];
```

In javascript. Is there any equivalent for Ruby?

Comment: If you have to create variables with dynamic names your code is most likely broken. Consider putting the elements into an array/dict-like container.

Comment: Its because I have nested arrays and would like to bring them up a level. So rather than saying container[0][0] Id like to have a bunch of top level arrays to access. In fact its kind of a necessity. It wouldn't be a common thing that I would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
window = {}
5.times do |i|
  window["my_new_array_#{i}"]=[]
end
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants actual variables and not an object called `window` (which is the global scope in JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

That same code does work in Ruby, too, and does the same thing.

Comment: only number should be converted into string `window['MyNewArray-' + i.to_s] = [];`

Comment: @fl00r: Ah yes, that's right. The idiomatic way would be to be to use string interpolation: `window["MyNewArray-#{i}"] = []`.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can create a Ruby hash using :

```
h = {}
```

and then add a key/value pair using the `store` or the `[]=` operator.

Like this :

```
h["foo_#{i}"] = []
```

[Documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000729)

Answer (score 1):

```
window = Hash[1.upto(5).map { |n| ["name-#{i}", []] }]
```